# Realm Authentication OkHttp call gets interrupted

Tags: android, authentication, realm, interrupt, realm-mobile-platform

I have set up Realm Object Server on Google CE. In my Android client, I use Firebase Sign in, from which I obtain a token. I, of course, forward this token to ROS to authenticate against Firebase on its own. Everything in this flow seems to be working, as the Realm sign in doesn't fail and returns SyncUser which I use to create a SyncConfiguration. Also, I can see new Realm appeared in my ROS web admin.

The thing is, any data I create with `Realm.getInstance(syncConfiguration)` is not stored at the server. I think so because if I create some data, reinstall the app and then re-authenticate, my synced realm is empty.

However, I have noticed an important thing after turning on debug logs for `RealmLog`. And that is the following stack trace:

```
D/REALM_JAVA: AuthenticateResponse - Error: UNKNOWN(-1)
java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:146)
at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:75)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.finishRequest(Http1xStream.java:161)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:51)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.authenticate(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:110)
at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.loginToRealm(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:63)
at io.realm.SyncSession$2.execute(SyncSession.java:225)
at io.realm.SyncSession$2.execute(SyncSession.java:221)
at io.realm.internal.network.ExponentialBackoffTask.run(ExponentialBackoffTask.java:66)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I don't know exactly why this happens, but I would say that it is connected to the lifecycle of Realm instance. Concretely to the case that my Realm instances are usually short lived. In my application, the Realm is an implementation detail, so I try to keep it as deep as possible. When I want to query data, I open Realm instance, select RealmObjects, map them to my business logic entities and then close Realm immediately.

Can anybody confirm that in order to have Realm synchronization properly working, I have to have long living Realm instances? Does the Realm instance have to have enough time to asynchronously prepare for syncyng before I can close it again? Or is there some other approach I should be aware of while working with ROS?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered keeping the UI thread Realm instance open if there are more than 1 activities open? Also if you immediately close the Realm, how are you listening for changes made remotely?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I have considered it. I am not interested in live updates in my project. Having snapshot of the data is well enough, I am interested mostly in the backup capabilities of such solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @bakua, yes right now the Session towards the server is tied to the Realm lifecycle. It is something we want to change going forward though, so you have more manual control over it.

Comment: I see. In that case, I'll change my approach to how I manage Realm instances. Thank you.